# How to destroy Button in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScriptToVisibleButton : MonoBehaviour
{

public NextLevelTeleportScript LvlEnd;
public Button button;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    if (LvlEnd = 1)
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

}
}
```

/////////////

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NextLevelTeleportScript : MonoBehaviour
{

public int LvlEnd = 0;

void Start()
{

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    LvlEnd = 1;
}

void Update()
{

}
```

/////////// in this link is screen shot of error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up9ru.png

can someone answer me quickly. I'm in a hurry. This script is supposed to work so that when I change the scene I get a button to the next level. (1 is true and 0 is false)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Also just because you are using a certain IDE this question isn't automatically about that IDE in specific ... rather tag the actual essential thing: You are using `unity3d`!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that error is due to your if statement:

```
if (LvlEnd = 1)
```

Try:

```
if (LvlEnd.LvlEnd == 1)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rrrrrr said, your if is wrong and the other thing I noticed is that you are referencing the script with the variable name in it, but you haven't actually accessed the variable. The right would be:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScriptToVisibleButton : MonoBehaviour
{

public NextLevelTeleportScript nextLevelTeleportScript; //just reference to script
public Button button;

void Start()
{
//You will probably need to reference the script either in the inspector, or around here. 
}

void Update()
{
    if (nextLevelTeleportScript.LvlEnd == 1) //now you get your variable and use
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

}
}
```

I think this will work!